# Hierarchical method for handling large class classification

Tags: deep-learning

I am looking for an ML algorithm which is appropriate for the following situation:

I am trying to pick out specific invoice numbers from remittance advice images which contain lots of irrelevant numbers which I wish to ignore. There are about 500,000 possible invoices to pick from, however, once I know one some information (customer name), the number of possible choices drops to a small number (between 1 and 50). There are other clues such as dates.

The possible invoice # values to pick from is continually changing, as once an invoice is paid, it will not be paid again and is no longer a possible answer.

One approach would be OCR and then try regex to match on available numbers.